# Differentiating under integral sign, what Theorem can I use?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

I have to prove that the following function is differentiable: $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ :
$$f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)\\=\int_{-a}^a(g(t)\cos(tx)-g(t)\sin(tx))e^{-ty}\,dt+i\int_{-a}^a(g(t)\cos(tx)+g(t)\sin(tx))e^{-ty}\,dt$$

Where $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with compact support.
To use the classical theorem I have to show that the integrand function and its partial derivative are both dominated by an $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ function.

The only thing that I can prove is that if $-a\leq t\leq a$, then for the $y$ derivative holds that

$$|-t| |(g(t)\cos(tx)-g(t)\sin(tx))e^{-ty}|\leq2|a\,g(t)| e^{a|y|}$$

Is there other theorem to apply?
Thanks

Comment: Does the support of $g$ lie in $[a,a]?$

Comment: @zhw. Yes, it is

Comment: In your estimate you should have $e^{a|y|}.$

Comment: @zhw. Thanks, updated.